# DeferredSXSSFWorkbook autosizing of columns

Tags: java, apache-poi, sxssf

Is it possible to autosize columns with `DeferredSXSSFWorkbook` / `setRowGenerator`?

I've set `rowAccessWindowSize` to 25 and attempt to autosize at row 20 but it doesn't do anything.

Simplified example:

```java
var wb = new DeferredSXSSFWorkbook(25);
var sheet1 = wb.createSheet("sheet1");
sheet1.setRowGenerator(sheet -> {
  sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
  var row = sheet.createRow(0);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Some very long string that exceeds default column width");
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
});
wb.write(new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx"));
```

Equivalent code with `XSSFWorkbook` (no streaming) works correctly.

Created a replit to demonstrate but for some reason it generates corrupted files: https://replit.com/@MarcinWinicki/DeferredSXSSFWorkbook-autosizing?v=1

Comment: Have you tried plain SXSSFWorkbook? DeferredSXSSFWorkbook may not support autosizing.

Comment: It does work just like XSSFWorkbook but it doesn't really do streaming hence I specifically asked for deferred one. I didn't find any documentation about sizing being unsupported and POI doesn't generate any warnings so it's hard to tell if I'm making some mistake or it's expected behavior.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/index.html?org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/DeferredSXSSFWorkbook.html -- this class is marked as `@Beta` and mentions in its description that it is experimental. One external contributor provided a PR and that's it -- noone has touched it since. POI's code base is gigantic and the volunteer base is small.

Comment: I'm aware. Just hoping someone went through the pains of using it and has some findings to share